# Android java I have a image thats supposed to be a bullet

Tags: java, android

So, I have a button and a image, the image is at the bottom of the screen and I want it so you can click on the button and the image will slide up the screen but you can keep pressing the button more and it will keep multiplying at the bottom of the screen and they all will just keep flying up the screen when ever the button was pressed and disappearing kinda like a bullet

How can I Do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a RelativeLayout.  onClick, loop over the existing imageview(s) and change the layoutparameters to move up the screen; otherwise, create a new imageview, set its src and initial position, and add it to your relativelayout.

(If there is only ever one imageview at a time, you don't need to create a new one, just move the old one back from off screen.)

Comment: The idea of it multiplying is what if they want to spam the bullets? So i want it so there could be like 6 or 8 flying up the screen at once

Comment: Then add a new ImageView on every click (up to some reasonable limit or your app will slowly grind to a halt) before doing the loop to update the positions of the existing views.